# nodemailer sender is empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I am trying to use nodemailer with an app that doesn't require any kind of verification. The server the app sits on has been whitelisted, so no username or password is required. 
I setup my mail config as follows:

```
let mailConfig = {
         pool: true,
        maxConnections: maxConnections,
        maxMessages: maxMessages,
        rateDelta: rateDelta * 1000,
        rateLimit: maxMessages * maxConnections,
        secure: false,
        ignoreTLS: true,
        logger:true,
        host: config.SMTP_Host,
        port: config.SMTP_Port
    };
```

However I keep bumping into a 550 error because the sender of the email isn't present. I found another stackoverflow question that states when you have a different host domain than the domain of the user (the user in this case being undefined) the sender automatically gets set to that. Which makes sense as to why my sender is being set to blank, even though I have in fact set it.

Is there a way to prevent nodemailer from changing the sender to match the user domain, if the user domain isn't present?

Or am I completely misunderstanding the error message?

So far I've tried to manually set these fields by doing this in the message object but I have to admit I'm not familiar with this type of protocol.

```
sender:config.SMTP_Host,
envelope: {
           from: `"Sender Name" <${config.SMTP_Host}>`, // used as MAIL FROM: address for SMTP
           to: `${email}, "${first_name}" <${email}>` // used as RCPT TO: address for SMTP
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The from field must contain an email address not a hostname.

If we use gmail as an example what you're putting in the from field is

```
From: "Sender Name" <smtp.gmail.com>
```

When it should be:

```
From: "Sender Name" <sender@gmail.com>
```

The sending server is searching for "smtp.gmail.com" as a email and isn't finding it so you get a message saying the email address doesn't exist.